# Syncthing failed item: "directory is not empty"

Tags: backup, sync, syncthing

I'm using Syncthing on my home network to keep my various machines in sync. One of my directories insists it's "Out of Sync":

[image: Syncthing showing three failed items]

The detail claims this is because of the "Backups" subdirectory, saying "delete dir: directory is not empty":

[image: Syncthing error message]

What's up with this? My `~/Sync/Backups/` folder was syncing just fine, seems to exist on all my machines, etc. How do I get Syncthing to go back to syncing it?